# Why the dispersion law have the form $\omega(\mathbf{k}_{1}+\mathbf{k}_{2})=\omega(\mathbf{k}_{1})+\omega(\mathbf{k}_{2})$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, particle-physics, dispersion

In the book [Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Field Theory](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/11222) by Albert Schwarz they define a particle corresponding to the Hamiltonian $H$, as a generalized vector function $\Phi(\mathrm{k})$, obeying
$$
\begin{aligned}
H \Phi(\mathbf{k}) &=\omega(\mathbf{k}) \Phi(\mathbf{k})  \\
\mathbf{P} \Phi(\mathbf{k}) &=\mathbf{k} \Phi(\mathbf{k}) \\
\left\langle\Phi(\mathbf{k}), \Phi\left(\mathbf{k}^{\prime}\right)\right\rangle &=\delta\left(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}^{\prime}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
The function $\omega(\mathbf{k})$ is called the energy of a single-particle state or the dispersion law.

Now at page 68 they claim  that every particle $\Phi(\mathbf{k})$ can be written in the form
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Phi(\mathbf{k})=& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \int \delta\left(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}_{1}-\cdots-\mathbf{k}_{n}\right) \\
& \times \phi_{n}\left(\mathbf{k}_{1}, \ldots, \mathbf{k}_{n}\right) a_{1}^{+}\left(\mathbf{k}_{1}\right) \ldots a_{n}^{+}\left(\mathbf{k}_{n}\right) \theta d \mathbf{k}_{1} \ldots d \mathbf{k}_{n}
\end{aligned}
$$
Where $\theta$ is the vacuum state.

I am trying to proof that $H \Phi(\mathbf{k}) =\omega(\mathbf{k}) \Phi(\mathbf{k})$. For example  for $n=2$
we would obtain the expression

$$
\begin{aligned}
  H\int \delta\left(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}_{1}-\mathbf{k}_{2}\right) 
 \phi_{n}\left(\mathbf{k}_{1}, \mathbf{k}_{2}\right) a_{1}^{+}\left(\mathbf{k}_{1}\right) a_{2}^{+}\left(\mathbf{k}_{2}\right) \theta d \mathbf{k}_{1}d \mathbf{k}_{2}=\\ \int \left(\omega(\mathbf{k}_{1})+\omega(\mathbf{k}_{2})\right)\delta\left(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}_{1}-\mathbf{k}_{2}\right) 
 \phi_{n}\left(\mathbf{k}_{1} \mathbf{k}_{2}\right) a_{1}^{+}\left(\mathbf{k}_{1}\right) a_{2}^{+}\left(\mathbf{k}_{2}\right) \theta d \mathbf{k}_{1}d \mathbf{k}_{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

If we could  proof that $\omega(\mathbf{k}_{1}+\mathbf{k}_{2})=\omega(\mathbf{k}_{1})+\omega(\mathbf{k}_{2})$
than due to the delta function we would have $H \Phi(\mathbf{k}) =\omega(\mathbf{k}) \Phi(\mathbf{k})$.

My question is why $\omega(\mathbf{k}_{1}+\mathbf{k}_{2})=\omega(\mathbf{k}_{1})+\omega(\mathbf{k}_{2})$?

Comment: Unless I've missed something, neither massless scalars ($\omega = |\mathbf{k}|$) nor massive scalars ($\omega = \sqrt{\mathbf{k}^2 + m^2}$) obey this relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the book, but I suspect that you are misunderstanding something.

There are two problems with what you say. 1) Your expression for $\Phi(k)$ is not a state in the Hibert space. You are missing the vacuum state $|0\rangle$ on which the creation opertors act to create the states.  2) After you insert the $|0\rangle$ the resulting $n$-particle state is not an eigenstate of $H$. It is however an eigenstate of $P$ that is a linear superposition of eigenstates of $H$.

EDit: Ah I see the $\theta$. Your next statement is not correct though. Just becuse $A$ and $B$ commute does not mean that every eigenstate of $A$ is an eigenstate of $B$.  You can have
$$
A= \left[\matrix{a &0 \cr 0& a}\right], \quad B= \left[\matrix{b &0 \cr 0& 2b}\right],
$$
so that $A$ and $B$ commute, but
$$
A= \left[\matrix{a &0 \cr 0& a}\right]\left[\matrix{1\cr 1}\right]= a  \left[\matrix{1\cr 1}\right]\quad B= \left[\matrix{b &0 \cr 0& 2b}\right]\left[\matrix{1\cr 1}\right]=  b\left[\matrix{1\cr 2}\right] 
$$
so eigenvector of $A$ but not of $B$.

Comment: The vacuum is there, albeit with a weird notation. He calls it $\theta$. As for your second comment I must be missing something, $H= P^0$ and $P^0$ commutes with $P^i$, so eigenstates of momentum must be eigenstates of $H$.

Comment: I'll add an edit.